# Multiple AWS Cred in Java Spring

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

In my POC project, we would like to use S3 from one AWS user account (AWS api key set 1) and SQS from other AWS user account (AWS api key set 2)?

I checked article below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html

As per this article we can build credential provider, but (as per my understanding) often credential provider is global value in java application...  Can we use multiple key sets in single Spring boot application?

Answer (score 2):

Credentials Providers in Spring are not global, but you can make them global by creating a Bean.

Instead what you can potentially do is create two separate components: one for SQSClient another for S3Client, both configured using a different AWS Account and then autowire them as per need.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Configuration
public class AwsClientConfig {

    //AWS Account 1: region1/accessKey1/secretKey1
    @Bean
    public AmazonSQS awsSQSClient(SqsConfig sqsConfig) {
        AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey1, secretKey1)))
                .withRegion(Regions.fromName(region1))
                .build();
        return sqs;
    }

    //AWS Account 2: region2/accessKey2/secretKey2
    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 s3Client() {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey2, secretKey2)))
                .withRegion(region2)
                .build();
        return s3Client;
    }

}
```

If you do not want to provide accessKey/secretKey inside codebase, you can either move them to application.yml or use `new ProfileCredentialsProvider("profile-1")` & `new ProfileCredentialsProvider("profile-2")`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to provide multiple accessKeys and SecretKeys in the application.yml? I've spent a week searching how to do this

Comment: You can basically add them under new configure parameters in your application.yml file and then have them retrieved with @Value annotation 
ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html